# my.ini File is missing since i want to reset my root password in mysql

Tags: mysql

[SEE THE LOCATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDsH5.jpg)

As you all can se **my.ini** file is missing what could be done?

Comment: *what could be done?* (1) Recover it from backup (2) Recover it from shadow copy (3) Undelete (4) Create new (5) Ignore - server will be set to defaults.

Comment: PS. Check service starting command line - maybe the file in another location is used? Read [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Using Option Files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html), check all candidate locations.